# Can not insert a new array field by using $set operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working with mongo and mongoose to update a array filed to a existing document.

Here is my original document

```
{
    device_id : 'abc', 
    is_online : false
}
```

I need to update two fields, one is `'is_online'` field, another is `'actuators'` field, which is an array field:

```
var update = {};
update.is_online = false;
update.actuators = [
    {
        'port': 1, 
        value: 0, 
        'type': 'binary',
        description: 'button 0'
    },
    {
        'port': 2, 
        value: 0, 
        'type': 'binary',
        description: 'button 1'
    }
]; 

DeviceModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { device_id: device_id },
    { $set: update },
    { new: false, upsert: true },
    function(err, doc) {

    }
)
```

but this only updates the existing field 'is_online', but does not insert the new array field.

What is the problem?

Comment: Please share the `schema`.

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to push the values to array instead $set
DeviceModel.update({device_id: device_id},{$pushAll: {actuators:update.actuators}},{upsert:true},function(err){
        if(err){
                console.log(err);
        }else{
                console.log("Successfully added");
        }
});
```